# Кнопка "тревога" при проверке сообщений

Tags: дефект

При проверке сообщений низкого качества, не отображается кнопка тревога, однако когда в сообщении лишь матерная лексика уместнее было бы не закрывать, а удалять вопрос сразу через модератора.

---

Хотел отправить вопрос до линии, но пишет, что тело вопроса не соответствует стандартам качества проекта. Пришлось добавить эту ненужную информацию, может эти правила тоже ослабить.

Comment: Про «соответствует стандартам качества проекта» — есть такая проблема. Пока не исправили, можно добавлять что-то ненужное и удалять после публикации.

Answer (score 1):

> через модератора

Модераторов на сайте вроде бы нет: https://rus.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Кнопки, имеющиеся в интерфейсе проверки, предназначены для *типичных* действий. Если же объект проверки выходит за рамки типичного, нужно перейти к нему непосредственно: для этого есть ссылка в правой колонке, или можно просто кликнуть по заглавию вопроса. И оттуда подавать тревоги и т.п.

Comment: На сайте есть модератор. Он не показывается в этом списке, потому что является сотрудником компании (а в списке — только назначенные или избранные волонтёры). http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/users/2/nicolas-chabanovsky

Comment: Ну вот, вы сменили имя и я теперь вам очевидные вещи рассказываю )

Answer (score 1):

С ответами целиком из матерной лексики вы можете справиться и без модератора. Выберите «тревога» — «невежливый или оскорбительный». Это создает сразу несколько последствий для оскорбительного вопроса или ответа:

- [Дух сообщества](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) голосует против этого сообщения.
- Добавляется единичка к «счетчику» тревог. Как только будет 6 тревог типа «спам» или «оскорбления» от разных участников, сообщение будет удалено.
- Тревога становится видна на специальной модераторской странице. Если модератор заметит её раньше, чем наберётся 6 тревог, то он сам удалит проблемное сообщение.

Кроме того у вас [есть 4000 репутации](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) и вы можете самостоятельно проголосовать за удаление сообщения. Это ещё более приблизит его к удалению.

Ещё вы можете просто отредактировать сообщение и вырезать лишнее. Если вырезать нужно всё, можно заменить каким-нибудь шаблоном. Я обычно пишу «Здесь был спам, но его удалили. Отметьте этот вопрос тревога — спам.»

А вообще, спасибо что разбираете очередь проверки. Очень нужная работа, хотя и почти не вознагражадаемая.